# Cannot run UIMA Ruta programs (imports not working?)

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

I am completely new to Ruta (and to Java).

I installed Eclipse, Maven plugin and Uima Ruta on my computer. I followed the instructions from the UIMA Ruta Guide and Reference. Eclipse shows I have got UIMA Runtime 2.10.2, UIMA Tools 2.10.2, UIMA Ruta Workbench 2.6.1 and UIMA-AS Deployment Descriptor Editor 2.10.3.

But now it turns out that I cannot write (well, compile/run) a single most simple program using Ruta because something is wrong with the imports.

When I write "PACKAGE uima.ruta.example", a red circle appears saying "The package declaration does not match the project structure" -- even if there is no other line in my program.

When I try to compile and run a simple program on an input file (right click on file > UIMA Ruta > Quick Ruta), nothing happens.

I suppose some important files simply haven't been downloaded onto my computer. When I am exploring the directory where I (think I) installed everything, I see there are loads of different "uima" amd "uimaj" packages in there, but I cannot find any packages called 'ruta' or 'ruta.example' or so.

What should I do? Where can I get the 'ruta' library? Does the 'ruta.example' library really exist or is it used in the book just as an example?

(Actually I would also be happy to receive an answer to the question "Why in God's name should I download an environment, install a plugin for it, install a subplugin for it, create a project for it and adjust its settings before writing some programs, instead of just installing and/or compiling some single stuff and just running my program with it in the command line?", but since such a way has not appeared yet officially (has it?), I suppose there should be some serious reasons for that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a declaration like `PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;` it's also required that you put that file in the matching package (directory). So, if your Ruta file names MyExample.ruta it should be located in script/uima/ruta/example/MyExample.ruta. If the Ruta workbench is installed correctly, and you create a default UIMA Ruta project, then it's possible to execute the Ruta file via the file context menu. No additional resources have to be downloaded.

Don't forget to add example input files into the "input" directory. These will be processed and the result will be placed in the "output" directory.

If you are using the Ruta library in Maven project (In a custom project other then running it through the Ruta workbench of Eclipse) you have to add Ruta as dependency in the `pom.xml`. All transitive dependencies will be downloaded by the Maven system.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
  <artifactId>ruta-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have hoped there were more built-in functions. But, still, there is one problem: I cannot use almost _anything_. The only two words my Ruta seems to know are DECLARE and REGEXP. I cannot use "BREAK" (Ruta does not know it even though it is promised in the Ruta book that BREAK is a valid Ruta word), so I try to declare "BREAK". But I cannot just do it. There should be a type before "{REGEXP...", but even when I write "ALL{REGEXP...", the word ALL is highlighted with grey. Same with ANY and the other types that I thought were available just after installation. What should I do next?

Comment: All the basic annotation types like BREAK, NBSP, WS, COMMA, CW, ...are available by default. There is no need to declare them in the script itself.

Comment: Actions cannot be used everywhere. The command structure of a scriptline in Ruta is.

```<pattern for matching> { <filtering/condition on match> -> <action> };```

Comment: Okay, but what should I do if these annotation types are not available on my machine and are shown in grey? How can I learn which files or settings are missing?

Comment: Please give more information what you have tried to solve it and give for example a script you build that's not working. If DECLARE is recognized then the Ruta Lexer seems to be is working.